# module has no submodule

Tags: python, import, module

I am making a flask web app and I have something I don't understand.

My `app` module folder structure goes like this :

```
app\
  | static\
  | templates\
  | tmp\
  | __init__.py
  | run.py <= debug script
  | toolxls.py <= helper functions 
  | views.py
```

in my **init**.py :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

now if I import app module from IDLE:

```
>>> import app
>>> dir(app)
['Flask', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'app', 'views']
```

module `app` has no `toolxls` sub-module. How can I add toolxls.py into `app`?

Comment: Have you tried `from . import views`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, submodules are *not* imported when you import the package. You must import them explicitly if you want access to their namespace.

```
import app.toolxls
```

Comment: after `from app import toolxls` I can access `app.toolxls`. My question : How can I access `toolxls` from app in `app`'s `__init__.py`?

Comment: I meant that after adding `from app import toolxls` to `__init__.py` I can use `toolxls` from elsewhere via `app.toolxls`. the behavior I don't understand is, `app` isn't initialized before `__init__.py` but `__init__.py` can access `app` and import `toolxls`. How is this possible?

Comment: Python doesn't require initialization to be complete.