# Package import creates a module, submodules still importable

Tags: python, import, rpm, distutils, setup.py

I've been working on a python package and now I would like to turn it into a small RPM distribution. Package includes a few modules, one of which is executable. I can create the RPM-package with `python setup.py bdist_rpm` and install it on a fedora box with `rpm`.

At this point have the desired command `myscript` and it works like a charm. But when i try to import the package in `ipython`, I run into something strange. I can do the following

```
from myscript import sdf
import myscript.mol2
```

Both work flawlessly, but

```
import myscript
myscript.sdf
```

throws

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sdf'
```

I've been working with this for a while now to no avail. There's plenty of questions of import problems, but I haven't found an answer for this one yet.

**What I should change to make it work?**

The current folder structure is:

```
myscript/  #project root
  setup.py
  src/
    myscript/
      __init__.py
      functions.py
      sdf.py
      mol2.py
      runner.py
  bin/
    myscript  #symbolic link to src/myscript/runner.py
```

`setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name = 'myscript',
      version = '0.75',
      author ='me',
      requires = ['numpy'], 
      packages = ['myscript'],
      package_dir = {'myscript':'src/myscript'},
      scripts = ['bin/myscript']
      )
```

and `__init__.py` is:

```
__all__ = ['functions','sdf','mol2','runner']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is normal behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563559/module-has-no-submodule) If you want submodules to be imported then you must import them in the module.

```
# myscript/__init__.py

from . import sdf
```

Comment: I thought so too, but with the rpm installed, `import myscript` throws `ImportError: cannot import name sdf`. The script crashes to the same error.

Comment: My bad, error was because i hadn't added `sdf.py` to my git repo, from which i had pulled the project. So there was no `sdf.py` to import.