# Python list com ports

Tags: python, serial-port

I am unable to list com ports using python :

```
import serial

print serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
```

Running the program gives this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\pystest\pystest\py stest.py", line 5, in 
>       print serial.tools.list_ports.comports() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tools' Press any key to continue . . .

Please help. Tried from `from serial import Serial` . It again gives the same error.

Edit : [module has no submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563559/module-has-no-submodule) does not address my issue. It's related to Flask. I'm using serial port and I've tried different combinations of importing sub module as I've already mentioned.

Here's a try as per the advise given on the comment :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you bother trying `import serial.tools.list_ports`?

Comment: Yes I did!! It makes no difference. I can edit the question and post the results of that id you'd like

Comment: Why would you change from trying to run `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` to trying to run `comports()`?

Comment: since ive imported it

Comment: You've made the namespace available. You haven't done anything to copy the names it contains to the local scope.

Comment: Now it works when I use serial.tools.list_ports.comports(). Thanks

Comment: Could you please help me on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283873/cx-freeze-a-python-program-which-uses-serial-ports-gives-error

Comment: I've never used cx_Freeze.