# 'module' object has no attribute 'to_bytes' Python

Tags: python, serial-port, cx-freeze

Please advise how I can cx-freeze my python program which uses serial :

```
    import serial    
    import serial.tools.list_ports;

    print serial.tools.list_ports()
```

Here's my setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    setup(
        name = "My test program",
        version = "3.1",
        description = "My test",
        executables = [Executable("pystest.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

After I build using cx_freeze, this is my error :

```
---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "pystest.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports.py", line 27, in <module>
    from serial.tools.list_ports_windows import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\tools\list_ports_windows.py", line 127, in <module>
    Ports = serial.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 115]) # "Ports"
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I'm not sure why I see this error. Any advise appreciated.

Here's a screenshot for easy reading :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: added import serial. I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
path = ["pystest"]+sys.path

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","serial"], "excludes": ["tkinter"],"path":path}
#add more package what are using for your app?

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "My test program",
        version = "3.1",
        description = "My test",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("pystest.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: I still get the same error. This makes no difference.

Comment: Added the path variable to my setup.py as you suggested.. Still does not work

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on my solution

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up doing this :

1. Modfying the file list_ports_windows.py inside C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\serial\tools and changed serial to serialutil like this :

> ```
> Ports = serialutil.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 115]) # "Ports"
> PortName = serialutil.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101]) # "PortName"
> ```

2. Then Added `from serial import serialutil` to the imports

Not sure if this is the right or wrong way but then it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: `PortName = serial.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101]) # "PortName"` Yes my library include this. Update your libraries on python !
What is verion ? my is 2.6

Comment: Serial version ? inside  ` __init__.py` ?

Comment: On IDLE : `import serial; serial.VERSION`

Answer (score -1):

Ports = serial.to_bytes([80, 111, 114, 116, 115]) # "Ports"  no attribute 'to_bytes'
two step:

1、pip install pyserial==3.4

2、pip install pyserial==2.7

i don't know the reason, but it worked